# How to evaluate the following c program?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
  int main() {
  int x;
  x=~!printf;
  printf("%x",x);
}
```

can some one explain me the process to derive the output of this program.

Comment: Take it a piece at a time. What's the meaning of `printf` with no parentheses after it? What does the `!` operator do? What does the `~` operator do?

Comment: Strictly speaking, your program causes undefined behaviour, since you're trying to print an `int` with the `%x` format.

Comment: @CarlNorum But isn't the `%x` format for printing an `int` in hexadecimal?

Comment: @CarlNorum that's not true. Specifying x without length defaults to unsigned int

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Strictly speaking, `%x` expects an `unsigned int`, not an `int`. Realistically, on most implementations, it will "work", except when the argument is negative, which it probably will be in this case - hence undefined (but probably not fatal) behavior....

Comment: @Nirk: So why is that 'undefined'? Won't it 100% of the time print whatever the value of `x` is as an unsigned integer?

Comment: “o,u,x,X The unsigned int argument is …” C99 7.19.6.1:8 “If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.” 7.19.6.1:9

Comment: @PascalCuoq: ah gotcha, thanks. so by the spec it's undefined, but most compilers end up doing something more or less sane.

Comment: @Nirk, no it's still for `unsigned int`.  I've never met a compiler that didn't "do the right thing", but it's still not strictly correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `printf` is a pointer to the `printf` function - thus it's ultimately an integer of some sort.
- `!` is unary NOT, meaning it returns `0` if the operand is true, and `1` is the operand is false. Since `printf` is true (non-zero, because the function is defined), the subexpression so far is `0`.
- `~` is bitwise complement. It flips all the bits of the binary number it is given. Since it is given `0`, this will return `0xffffffff`.
- That result is then stored into `x` and printed out in hexadecimal.

On a 64-bit machine you might instead get `0xffffffffffffffff`, though I'm not entirely certain.

Comment: If someone could comment, I'm also not entirely sure what unary NOT returns. Various websites say it returns true or false, but AFAIK C doesn't have a true or false data type. So, if it returns 1 or 0, what is the bitwidth of that 1 or 0?

Comment: All of the logical operators (`!`, `!=`, `==`, `&&`, and `||`) return `int`. C99 (and newer) *do* have a boolean type, too.

Comment: @CarlNorum: ah ok. and according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types), `int` is defined as a signed integer which is at least 16 bits in size. so depending on what `int` is for the compiler & platform, you'll get the largest int possible for either 16-bits, 32-bits, 64-bits, etc..

Comment: ... or 23 bits or 18 bits or 1384 bits or whatever, yes.